# Unable to write to database but able to read

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string, readonly

In my windows form application, I have placed database with in the project.

But I am not able to write anything into the database. My winforms can read all the contents of the database.

How can I solve this problem?

Currently the database is in the following location:

```
C:\Users\Amrit\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Purchase Management\Purchase Management\Resources\App_Data
```

In `app.config` file I have this configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Database" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Resources\App_Data\Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="Purchase_Management.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Resources\App_Data\Database.accdb"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

And I am accessing the database from classes using this;

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: So what happens when you *do* try to write?

Comment: Does a user in the database has the permission to write?

Comment: Well the root project folder says readonly. But even i remove readonly and check back, it becomes readonly again

Comment: @AmritSharma are you allowed to write to the database? as the user?

Comment: nope. If i place my database in desktop, i am able to write but if i place it in the project folder, i cannot

Comment: As I said in your other question, the database file from the project folder is copied over the one in your output folder. That's why you don't see the output.

Comment: tell me where am i supposed to put the database file if i need to create setup file for this application

Comment: but when i create setup file with installShield, the appliction doesnot find the location of the database, i provide location in app.config as connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Resources\App_Data\Database.accdb"

Answer (score 0):

I think, SQL File Writer service has no write access to that folder. 
You can set ACL or change folder.